# Font Bold in Label Xamarin Forms

Tags: fonts, xamarin.forms

This is my Label of my ContentPage:

```
<Label FontSize="Small"
       Grid.Row="0"
       Grid.Column="0"
       VerticalOptions="Center" 
       Text="{Binding ItemCode,StringFormat='Code: {0}'}">
</Label>
```

I would like to apply the Bold Font to this part of the text "Code:", is there a way to do it on the axml page?

Comment: Not without using a custom renderer. If you don't want to create a custom renderer, then you'll have to create two labels; one for 'Code:' which you can set to bold, and another for whatever value `ItemCode` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms use `XAML`, not `AXML`.

**Use two separated Label tags:**

```
<Label FontSize="Small" 
       Grid.Row="0" 
       Grid.Column="1" 
       VerticalOptions="Center" 
       FontAttributes="Bold"
       Text="Code :">
</Label>

<Label FontSize="Small" 
       Grid.Row="0" 
       Grid.Column="1" 
       VerticalOptions="Center" 
       Text="{Binding ItemCode,StringFormat='{0}'}">
</Label>
```

Edit: Wrapping it on a StackLayout with `Horizontal` Orientation they'll be on the same 'line'.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `FormattedText` property to set the parts off your text.
Like this:

```
<Label Grid.Row="0"
       Grid.Column="0"
       FontSize="Small"
       VerticalOptions="Center" >
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <FormattedString.Spans>
                <Span Text="Code: "
                      FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                <Span Text="{Binding ItemCode}" />
            </FormattedString.Spans>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```